# How to tell typescript about functions "mixed in" from another module?

Tags: typescript, class, mixins

I have this situation:

```
// Application.ts
import MicroEvent from 'microevent-github'

class Application {
  // stuff...
  something() {
    // It is also saying "trigger" is undefined,
    // but it IS defined, MicroEvent defined it.
    this.trigger('foo')
  }
}

// get the `bind`, `unbind`, and other methods from MicroEvent
MicroEvent.mixin(Application)

const app = new Application()

const handleFoo = () => console.log('foo')

// try to use them, get the squiggly errors saying
// `bind` doesn't exist on Application, etc.
application.bind('foo', handleFoo)
application.unbind('foo', handleFoo)
```

I have "mixed in" the `MicroEvent` to my application, which adds some methods to the object. However, VSCode is complaining that `bind` and `unbind` don't exist on the Application instance... But it does, how do I tell typescript to accept this?

Adding this doesn't work:

```
type Application = {
  bind: (eventType: string, callback: () => void) => void
  unbind: (eventType: string, callback: () => void) => void
  trigger: (eventType: string) => void
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript doesn't know that the mixin is modifying the class.

You can fill it in with `declare` statements, which tell typescript that some types exist, but without providing any implementation. This is a bit dangerous in that you are creating an interface where there is no type checking that it's implemented safely, but when using an untyped library, you may not have a choice.

```
class Application {
    declare bind: (eventType: string, callback: () => void) => void
    declare unbind: (eventType: string, callback: () => void) => void
    declare trigger: (eventType: string) => void

    //...
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCAO8QEthgC7IPYDtoG8AoaaAEwFNQwAnc6AI2R1IC5oAKcgN3J3QBUAnvHJsI6akwDmAGmhoQIemGABrNuwCU0ALwA+aFyzJS2-YeOliZSuFrQArjkbMN3XgOGjo4yTlnyYIrKahpmBkYm4RYm1hRU9hLIUlLk1G48fEIiYkn+0ZFW1gD0xT7oDgBmlQB0ddYQWAC25OgAFtJaBNYkpdAAkujQyDBBjT5ggtLQAERJKWkzwzBOFJVM5KQyPdB99A5DyEP9AMo26zibcgCyqNRYAKKZQ2sbpMPoNTvtIzXzqdR2ABySpYLBAzTWAC+hBhhD6ABEsNB2nQmsgAB5MDikEZgeggTbDPA-GBISZSe6rSF9W7Ae5PDw1dFYnDsBBIVAYbA4SGEYC4cTQMCIXTQS4AdzgiBQaEwuC0hH5gqGbTAzEJADEwWKuuYBThGoSaiAsFJgaDwXy+vw2uQIHQcFgpRKsNRVIQRfAai5SBawUC5GqNeRtVhIV6ak5ff7wUH1aQtWDNEA)

---

To reuse this, you could create an abstract base class that declare these methods, and inherit from that.

```
abstract class MicroEventBase {
  declare bind: (eventType: string, callback: () => void) => void
  declare unbind: (eventType: string, callback: () => void) => void
  declare trigger: (eventType: string) => void
}

class Application extends MicroEventBase {
  //...
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgsgS1lA9gKIBuApgHYQBCapCA3gFAIIAmpKwUdI25rALgQAKUmUoAVAJ4AHUkMhQ+AcwA0SYMmQg4AayHCAlAgC8APgTF82VsfOXrrZmw6puCAK7le-A2IoQ0nIK0CrqsJraegZ2FlY2sQ42zuyc7qHKyqRQfuKBsvIIiiqJ8U4AvoyMnOgIAIIyMsi4wBDY+OQIpAAeEBSsGDh4RHk0YHRMLAD0U0UQHgBmCwB0q85g+AC2pBAAFipGDM7TswCSiNgYmhtFwFIqCABEGVlQjwiXnvykC3ykrKpjggZggQB4LohTgBlFy-cj-dRDAgkAKwv6sD4QZZAvaXZYvbLCADkC3w+CJhmclUqjBBABF8Ag9nRNthunwRKxLqBkP8Pp1cRgmndlAQvLZabMkSMAstWezyMIGk0Wm0OpTqh1IAhgI1TAh4QB3eqNZoRNWKjWwLWIXbAfi8gBiZP1h3s1vIG15y2Q+GUxNJ5I1IIku1I4wN+GNhvwUF0jF1MmWPlYAbJRPUdodpGd+EpieWXhTafJmftrCdZMMQA)